# I need to find the most used character in an input sentence, without using the Max() or Count() functions in Python

Tags: python, list, syntax

This is for my coding class.I have to write a program that lets the user enter a string and displays the character that appears most frequently in the string. I cannot use the max or the count functions. I am completely lost beyond this example that my book has pretty much.

I tried this:

```py
# lst = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]


def main():


    count = 0

    my_sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")

    for ch in my_sentence:
        if ch == 'T' or ch == 't':
            count += 1
    

    print('The letter T appears', count, 'times.')


main()
```

Which works for finding specific letters, but I just cannot for the life of me even begin to understand what I would do to find the most used letter in any sentence entered. I may be stupid. I've been trying to solve this problem for 10+ hours and I can't think anymore.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried just repeating these lines but as elif's?  
counta =0
if ch == 'A' or ch == 'a':
            counta += 1
When you are learning, sometimes it is ok and even good do go about trying out solutions that are not very good just to understand the problem space.  Please share your attempts with us.

Comment: Please don't ask StackOverflow to do your homework.  You won't learn anything that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to count, and then compare, the frequency of each letter:

```py
def most_frequent_character(sentence):
    character_frequency_dictionary = {} # make new dictionary to keep track of a character's frequency

    for character in sentence:
        # if we have not encountered this character before, set the count of the character to 1
        if character not in character_frequency_dictionary:
            character_frequency_dictionary[character] = 1

        # else, if we have see then character, increment the count of that character
        else:
            character_frequency_dictionary[character] += 1

    # now we have a dict of chars and their frequency, so we need to now see which is the most frequent

    # default values
    max_freq = 0
    most_freq_char = ''

    # compare each characters frequency to find the most frequent
    for character in character_frequency_dictionary:
        frequency = character_frequency_dictionary[character]

        if frequency > max_freq:
            max_freq = frequency
            most_freq_char = character

    return most_freq_char


print(most_frequent_character('abcdeaa')) # a
print(most_frequent_character('AAaaddd')) # d (not checking case)
print(most_frequent_character('abcffff')) # f
print(most_frequent_character('iiiiiii')) # i
print(most_frequent_character('abcdefh')) # a (first found)
```

If needed, convert string to lowercase (using 'string'.lower()) if you need this case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

While I was working on a solution, I do see that a couple of folks have come up with some solutions.  However, I will add this code to the mix to possibly give you one more direction for a solution.  Its basis is upon the usage of the "array" package, along with using the "ord" and "chr" functions to translate ASCII characters within an entered string.

```
import array as arr

def maxi(sentence):
    a = arr.array('i', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) # Character counter array

    c = '#'     # Work variable that will hold the character with the highest count
    d = 0       # Work variable that will hold the maximum count

    for x in range(len(sentence)):      # Parse each character of the entered string/sentence
        ch = ord(sentence[x:x+1])       # Convert to its ASCII value

        if ch >= 65 and ch <= 90:       # Uppercase character
            a[ch - 65] = a[ch -65] + 1

        if ch >= 97 and ch <= 122:      # Lowercase character
            a[ch - 97] = a[ch -97] + 1

    for x in range(26):                 # Now read through the character counter array and determine the character with the largest value
        if a[x] > d:
            c = chr(x + 65)
            d = a[x]
            
    print("The character with the highest count is", c, "with a count of", d)    

    return

sentence = input("Enter a sentence or string: ")

maxi(sentence)
```

I interspersed comments as to the functionality going on, but following are the key points.

- The "array" package is imported to allow for the storage of counts for each of the twenty-six characters that might be found in a string or sentence.
- As the string is parsed, the "ord" function is used to convert the parsed character into an integer value which is subsequently used to increment the appropriate character counter element in the array.
- After parsing, the count array is processed and the array element is tested, storing the associated character and its count when it is determined to currently be the character with the highest count.

Following was a quick test of this code.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Maximum$ python3 MaxChar.py 
Enter a sentence or string: My country tis of thee
The character with the highest count is T with a count of 3
```

As noted, just another train of thought to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the character that leaves the shortest rest when removed:

```py
min(sentence, key=lambda c: len(sentence.replace(c, '')))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3Y4pT80pS85JTFWwVlIrzc1MVYAJKXFwFRZl5JRq5mXkaMEEdhezUStucxNyklESFZCuFnFSEnF5RakFOYnKqRrKOgrq6JhBA7IBaBbMSAA)

You could use `min(set(sentence), ...)` or `min(alphabet, ...)` for more speed if necessary.

And do `sentence = sentence.upper()` beforehand if you want to treat lower and uppercase as the same character.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the most used character then you can sort the string and iterate of the characters keeping track of how many times the current character has occurred. When characters change you compare the count to the current max and update if it is greater.

````py
string = 'This can be any arbitrary string!!!!!!!'

#string = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), string)) #Use this if you only care about alphabet charactes
string = string.lower() 

char = ''
current_count = 0
max_count = 0
max_char = ''
for c in sorted(string):
    if char != c:
        if current_count > max_count:
            max_count = current_count
            max_char = char
        current_count = 1
        char = c
    else:
        current_count += 1
print(repr(max_char))```
````